# How can i put php code on the wordpress page?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

is it anyway possible to find a home page at all, I would like to insert php code on it, from cms I do not know if it's possible, I watched some plugins, but they do not look good to me. thank you all for help

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Just add some PHP to the home page, or to every page? Does it have to be at a specific position, or just executed in header or footer?

Comment: I want the user after the registration (when he clicked the button to register) to send one xml containing his data.
This xml code has variables in php and the data generated is sent directly to another server.
I thought that after the registration I posted a home page, I think that I could put this php code on my home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using [the user_registration hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) is probably the best fit for what you want to do.

An example from the docs:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', $_POST['first_name']);

}
```

To be compliant with the WordPress way (and be less likely to get into trouble if you change servers), you should probably use WP's [HTTP API](https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) to send the XML to the other URL.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you tell me if I need to put this code on the page where I want to enter my xml call?

Comment: Put it into the functions.php of your theme, or [build a simple plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

Comment: can I use the same page (function.php) to insert my xml call?https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bd8ab3f2a17342a64a0205b53740de1a

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Put it inside the function (e.g. `myplugin_registration_save`) that you add. Also note that it's functions.php (with an s at the end). function.php won't get executed automatically.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, I set this code up, is that okay?https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3faf8328dd68dffab0b0a3d25bc6b71b

Comment: The function definition for xml is missing. With add_action, the second parameter should be either a function name (in your case `xml`), an anonymous function or a callable. You should probably just add `function xml() {` after the line with add_action, as you have an unbalanced curly bracked at the end.